# Flipped normals and texture flickering on Motorola and Samsung Android phones

Tags: opengl, android, godot, mobile

What is happening to the textures when playing on the Motorola Android phone?

[image: Example of problem]

Deleting and creating new materials doesn't work, the problem persists even with new materials, material overlay or material override don't work either, actually even just simply leaving the meshes with 0 materials presents the same problem.

It looks like the normals are flipped on Motorola even though it's the same game file.

I tested on a Samsung and the problem persists there too. All of these are using OpenGL 2.

Comment: First guess is that Godot is trying to use some OpenGL extension that the Motorola device does not support. Perhaps disabling cull face would suffice? Anyway, consider reporting it as a bug at https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues